# Running electro-optic modulators in reverse

Tags: optoelectronics

An lithium niobate [electro-optic modulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro-optic_modulator) allows one to modulate the amplitude (or phase) of an optical signal by applying a bias. But what voltage would I measure across the bias input if I applied a premodulated optical signal to the device? In other words, can they be run in reverse, as a way to probe the optical signal incident on them?

I would go get one and find out, but the relevant lab is locked until Monday, and I'm an impatient man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an electro-optical modulator is a one-way device. The electrical signal can change the optical properties of the device, but a light signal has no effect on its electrical properties.